# How can I use 'this' instead of Main.ActiveForm?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code, which is throwing a NullReference exception when the form loses focus (when another program is clicked):

```
namespace MyProg
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Mouse Mouse = new Mouse();
            Thread Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Mouse.Hook));
            Thread.Start();
        }

        internal static bool IsTransparent = true;
        internal static void TransparentForm()
        {
            Main.ActiveForm.TransparencyKey = (Main.IsTransparent ? Color.Firebrick : Color.AliceBlue);
        }
    }

    public class Mouse
    {
        public void Hook()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if(Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
                {
                    if(Cursor.Position.X < 1300)
                    {
                        Main.IsTransparent = true;
                        Main.ActiveForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Main.TransparentForm));
                    }
                    // .....
                }
            }
        }
}
```

How can I eliminate `Main.ActiveForm`?

Comment: Why is this static, where are you calling this code and what are you tring to do?

Comment: You can't.. it appears to be static, so `this` is meaningless..

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I've edited my post to include some more code.

Comment: Are you calling this after the form has loaded?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Yes. But if another program is clicked when the `while` loop is running, it throws a null ref exception.

Comment: You can pass an argument to the thread start method.  Pass the form object, *this*.  Using a thread is a really bad idea, use a timer.

Comment: @HansPassant A thread is required. If I didn't use a 2nd thread, the main form would be forever frozen (while loop).

Comment: You really got that fundamentally wrong.  You *replace* a while loop with a timer.  You'll get yourself into a lot of trouble, which is okay I guess since there's nothing like the school of hard knocks to learn the craft thoroughly.  A book about Winforms programming will however soften the blows considerably.

Comment: @HansPassant I do have a `Thread.Sleep(10)` inside the end of the `while` loop. I need the cursor position to be constantly polled. Can you tell me what advantage there is to using a timer instead of a while loop combined with a thread sleep? The issue at hand here is the NullRef exception... not the loop.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specs for [`Form.ActiveForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx), it is supposed to return null if none of the forms in your program are active (which is the case if another program has the focus).

Try wrapping the call to `Main.ActiveForm.Invoke` inside an `if` that checks to make sure `Main.ActiveForm` isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

As a direct answer to your question, following your code style:

```
Thread Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Mouse.Hook));
        Thread.Start(this);
```

and then

```
public void Hook(object mainObject)
    {
        Main form = (Main)mainObject;
        while(true)
        {
             // ...
```